# How to get the first key value from map using JAVA 8?

Tags: java, java-8, iterator, java-stream

As for now I am doing :

```
Map<Item, Boolean> processedItem = processedItemMap.get(i);

        Map.Entry<Item, Boolean> entrySet = getNextPosition(processedItem);

        Item key = entrySet.getKey();
        Boolean value = entrySet.getValue();


 public static Map.Entry<Item, Boolean> getNextPosition(Map<Item, Boolean> processedItem) {
        return processedItem.entrySet().iterator().next();
    }
```

Is there any cleaner way to do this with java8 ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I see two problems with your method:

- it will throw an exception if the map is empty
- a `HashMap`, for example, has no order - so your method is really more of a `getAny()` than a `getNext()`.

With a stream you could use either:

```
//if order is important, e.g. with a TreeMap/LinkedHashMap
map.entrySet().stream().findFirst();

//if order is not important or with unordered maps (HashMap...)
map.entrySet().stream().findAny();
```

which returns an `Optional`.

Comment: Yeah, I will change to TreeMap. Can you let me know how do I get the Entry from Optional

Comment: can I just use .get() ?

Comment: @user3407267 `if (opt.isPresent()) Entry e = opt.get(); else doSomethingElse();`, for example. There are other ways depending on what you need/want.

Comment: Yes you can use get if you are 100% sure the optional is not empty (i.e. you know the map wasn't empty or you have tested with `isPresent`).

Comment: If you are going to do `if(opt.isPresent()) { Entry e = opt.get(); } else doSomethingElse();` anyway, there is no significant difference to `if(!map.isEmpty()) { Entry e = map.entrySet().iterator().next(); } else doSomethingElse();`

Answer (score 8):

Seems like you need `findFirst` here

```
   Optional<Map.Entry<Item, Boolean>> firstEntry =    
        processedItem.entrySet().stream().findFirst();
```

Obviously a `HashMap` has no order, so findFirst might return a different result on different calls. Probably a more suitable method would be `findAny` for your case.